# Size of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios4

When I tried to check the size of NSArray which is declared without any capacity, I found it 4. Now the question is why it is always 4? please help me out to find it....
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by checking the size?  Like `[someArray count]`?  Do you have a code example we could see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this:

```
NSArray *foo;
NSLog(@"%d", sizeof(foo));
```

You'll either get 4 or 8, depending on if you are on a 32 or 64 bit system.  Note that I quite purposefully didn't initialize `foo`;  there is no need to do so as `sizeof(foo)` is giving *the bytesize of `foo`* and `foo` is just a random pointer to an object.   Wouldn't matter if that were `id foo; void*foo; NSString*foo;` all would be 4 or 8.

If you want the allocated size of an instance of a particular class, the Objective-C runtime provides introspection API that can do exactly that.   However, I can't really think of any reason why that would be more than passingly interesting in a program.

Note that the allocation size of an instance does not account for any sub-allocations.  I.e. an NSArray likely has a backing store which is a separate allocation.

To reiterate:

### sizeof(foo) in the above code has nothing to do with the size of the allocated instance.

Comment: that means the size is dependent on the system. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not really;  the pointer size is, but, again, **sizeof(foo)** has *nothing* to do with the allocation!  Nothing at all!

Answer (score 13):

If you're talking about `sizeof`, it is *not* the right way to find out how much data an NSArray is holding. Objective-C objects are always accessed through pointers, and the size of a pointer on the iPhone is 4 bytes. That's what `sizeof` is telling you. To find out how many objects are in an array, ask the array for its `count`.

Comment: @Chuck: Nah, I was asking about the size of the array when we initialize it i.e. before adding any values or objects. I found that the size of the pointer to all the collection class is always 4, if yes then why?

Comment: @nil I have tried to check size using sizeOf and found 4 for every pointers of collection class(like array etc). Do the size of all pointers to collection class is always 4? if yes, than why?

Comment: @Milesh: As I said, on the iPhone's processor, all pointers are 4 bytes. The `sizeof` operator gives the size of the operand in bytes. Thus, `sizeof` on any object will give you 4. It is not the "size of the array" (no matter how you define that) — it's just the size of a pointer. Not just a pointer to an instance of a collection class, but any pointer.

Comment: @Chuck:so does it matter if the pointer is pointing to NSArray or any other collection class

Comment: @Milesh: As far as the size of the pointer is concerned, no, it doesn't matter at all. All pointers are four bytes on the iPhone's processor.