# Getting a null value in the NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite, nsmutablearray

My program contains three textfields and I am inserting the data into an sqlite database. Now I am trying to display the data from the database in the tableview. For that I tried to add the data into an NSMutableArray and tried to print that. But it is showing a null value in the array. I don't know why I am getting a null value. cont is the NsMutableArray.

```
    [cont addObject:name.text];
    [cont addObject:address.text];
    [cont addObject:phone.text];

    NSLog(name.text);
    NSLog(address.text);
    NSLog(phone.text);

    int length= sizeof(cont);


    NSString *strlen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length];
    NSLog(strlen);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen;i++)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *u = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSLog(u);
        NSLog(arr);

    }
```

I am always getting length as 4 and null in arr. Can anyone please tell me why it is so? I know there must be some error in the code.

Comment: Don't do sizeof() to get the length of an array, use the length method. sizeof(ANY_OBJECT) will just return your platform's equivalent of sizeof(void*)

Comment: Check whether your array is allocated

Comment: @Arshad yes it is . I have included the following code : NSMutableArray * cont=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use**

```
int length=[cont count];
       //array  count
```

**instead** of

int length= sizeof(cont);

and refer that Link

[Size of NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062496/size-of-nsarray)

**Sample**

```
NSMutableArray * cont=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [cont addObject:@"1"];
    [cont addObject:@"ddg"];
    [cont addObject:@"ggg"];

    for(int i=0;i<[cont count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Index %d",i);
        NSLog(@" Object %@",[cont objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    [cont release];
```

Comment: yes i have used this [cont count] but i am getting length as zero.Why it is so?

Comment: @user1626972 check  NSLog(@"%@",cont);

Comment: Nothing..I am getting output as ( ) .

Comment: Your array object is not added correctly .Check my edited ans

Comment: Ok i got that.But there is one problem.The values at index 0,1 and 2 are getting overwrite each time when i give the different values to the textfields.But i want the index to be increased.means next time when i submit another values, the value must be saved at the index 3 and so on.Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Don't alloc & release every time.alloc globally

Comment: Better you have to use nsobject class

Comment: But release is not available in ARC

Comment: allocate your array object globally & used it accordingly

Comment: No Rams.Still I am not getting.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
int length= sizeof(cont);
```

use 
`int length= [cont count];` 
instead

The sizeof(*) operator returns the size of the pointer to the NSMutableArray.

```
[cont count];
```

returns the no of elements in the array.

You are getting Null in arr because you are extracting a string `[cont objectAtIndex:i]` into an NSArray `NSArray *arr`

Use `NSString *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: yes i have used [cont count] before. But i am getting length as zero and also getting following error The array is:0 2012-08-27 14:32:16.901 db[925:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'                     can you please tell me Why i am getting this error? Thank you for your response

Comment: at first alloc and init the NSmutableArray. Then try adding simple strings(not from the textboxes) into the array and check if you still get the error.The array remains empty after your modification. Try taking the textbox values in strings and then add to the array.

Comment: I got that.But there is one problem.The values at index 0,1 and 2 are getting overwrite each time when i give the different values to the textfields.But i want the index to be increased.means next time when i submit another values, the value must be saved at the index 3 and so on.  I will post the code below :-

Comment: cont=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *Name = name.text;
NSString *Address = address.text;
NSString *Phone = phone.text;
            
[cont addObject:Name];
[cont addObject:Address];
[cont addObject:Phone];
            
              for(int i=0;i<[cont count];i++)
            {
                NSArray *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];
                
                NSLog(@"Index %d",i);
                NSLog(@" Object %@",arr);
                
            }
            
I have declared NSMutableArray *cont in @implementation . So can you please tell me how to increase the index value.

Comment: Initialize the cont array in viewDidLoad or anywhere else before the action method.everytime you enter the textbox values, the array gets initialized and adds 3 object.And change the NSArray *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i]; line to 'NSString' *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];....hope this time it helps........:)

Comment: ok thank i got that.Now i have one more doubt.I have successfully inserted this datas into sqlite db. Now my doubt is how to display all the datas from the table in another Storyboard? I will paste the code below.Please tell me if there is any wrong in the code.

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"contactDetails"]) {
   
        dbViewController1 *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
  
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

Comment: if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSMutableString *querySQL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ID =\"%d\"",1];
            
            NSLog(querySQL);
            
            [cont addObject:querySQL];
            NSLog(@"%@",cont);
 const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
            
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, 
                                   query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {

Comment: NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                    name.text =nameField;
                    
NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                    address.text = addressField;
NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
phone.text = phoneField;
status.text = @"Match found";

Comment: [cont addObject:querySQL];
[cont addObject:nameField];
[cont addObject:addressField];
[cont addObject:phoneField];
 NSLog(@"%@",cont);
} else { status.text = @"Match not found";
address.text = @"";
 phone.text = @"";
 }
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(contactDB);
        }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
[cont addObject:phone.text];
```

You're adding a `NSString`

```
NSArray *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];
```

And you're trying to extract a `NSArray`

Also a good practice for getting the size of an array is to use its `count` property, not `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because you print an array not the value at index::

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen;i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [cont objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `[cont count]` instead of `sizeof(cont)`

And... did you alloc + init your NSMutableArray?

```
cont = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and this line is wrong:

```
NSArray *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];
```

it should be

```
NSString *arr = [cont objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: yes i have used alloc and [cont count] before. But  still i am getting length as zero and also getting following error                       The array is:0
2012-08-27 14:32:16.901 db[925:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where is your mistake but to go through un array in objective-c you should use forin loop.

```
for (NSString* value in cont) {
    NSString *u = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    NSLog(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *strlen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length];
```

strlen is just a NSString, but you're trying to use it as integer on line:

```
 for(int i=0;i<strlen;i++)
    {
       ...

    }
```

You should use it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<[strlen intValue];i++)
        {
           ...

        }
```

`[strlen intValue]` will give you the correct result.
Good luck.